# Scala Spark: Extract name of the array-typed column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a schema that looks like following:

```
 |-- test: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- MOB: array (nullable = true)
```

Is it possible to extract the name of the array which is `MOB`?

Comment: can you please provide sample example, what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```scala
(
    df.schema("test")
      .dataType 
      .asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType] 
      .fields(0)
      .name
)
```